# Failed to import gs://bucket_name/Cloud.sql

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have stored everything needed for my database in phpmyadmin , and exported the my database from it. That was saved as Cloud.sql , so now this sql file I imported it to the Google Cloud Storage with the help of this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import_export.

Now after importing the Contents of .sql using the Import option present in the action of the instance, it shows the green working sign , and after a while it stops, when I check in the Logs , it shows 
Failed to import gs://bucket_name/Cloud.sql: An unknown problem occurred (ERROR_RDBMS)
So , 
I am unable to find out the reason behind the error as its not clear, and how can this be solved

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Sql probably doesn't know to which database the gs://bucket_name/Cloud.sql commands apply.

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/pFGe7LsbUaw:

> The problem is the dump doesn't contain the name of the database to use. If you add a 'USE XXX' at the top the dump where XXX is the database you want to use I would expect the import to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues that were spitting out the `ERROR_RDBMS` error.

It turns out that google actually does have more precise errors now, but you have to go here

`https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/{DATABASE_NAME}/operations`

And you will see a description of why the operation failed.